# VertexAI AutoML SavedModel's directory doesn't have the correct structure

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to export an AutoML model trained on VexterAI to Storage, but the structure of the directory of destiny is wrong. The model was exported with the format id `tf-saved-model`, a TensorFlow model. The command I used to export was the following:

```
response = model.export_model(export_format_id='tf-saved-model', artifact_destination='gs://storage_path/')
```

And I believe the destination directory should have the structure of a TensorFlow SavedModel like:

```
 model/
    ├── assets/
    │   ├── ...
    ├── saved_model.pb
    ├── variables/
    │   ├── ...
```

But my directory has the following structure:

```
model /
   ├── environment.json
   ├── feature_attributions.yaml
   ├── lower_bound/
   |   ├── 001/
   |   |   ├── assets.extra/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   |   |   ├── assets/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   |   |   ├── saved_model.pb
   |   |   ├── variables/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   ├── predict/
   |   ├── 001/
   |   |   ├── assets.extra/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   |   |   ├── assets/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   |   |   ├── saved_model.pb
   |   |   ├── variables/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   ├── upper_bound/
   |   ├── 001/
   |   |   ├── assets.extra/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   |   |   ├── assets/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   |   |   ├── saved_model.pb
   |   |   ├── variables/
   |   |   |   ├── ...
   | ...
```

I had already searched through so many documentation pages, and I didn't find what I'm doing wrong... Can someone help me?

Comment: I tried exporting my model and got the same result. It seems like an expected behavior. What issues do you encounter if you use this directory structure from AutoML?

Comment: I cannot import this directory on BigQuery, it doesn't recognize the structure and return an error about not finding a valid SavedModel. The BigQuery documentation says that is possible to import a TensorFlow SavedModel (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-tensorflow#importing_a_tensorflow_model) and the TensorFlow documentation says the structure of a SavedModel directory is the first structure I appointed. And when I tried to import a directory with this indicated structure, it works.

Comment: I see. You will be able to create a model if you point it to `model/lower_bound/*`, `model/predict/*` and `model/upper_bound/*`. Will you get your desired results if you create 3 separate models (one for each directory)?